# How to do bitwise logic for fitting box

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm not good in bit logic but I think it will be the best solution for my problem.

I have to find if an object can fit in a box, I won't consider 3D rotation but just simple 90° options.
So basically if the object can fit in any way inside the box.

I'm actually checking all the dimensions of the object against the dimensions of the box, so I know if `ObjWidth` can fit in `BoxWidth` OR `BoxLength` OR `BoxHeight` and so on with `ObjLength` and `ObjHeight`.
This is defined using a `Flag enum` for each dimension

```
enum En_Dimension
    {
        None = 0,
        Width = 1,
        Lenght = 2,
        Height = 4,
        All = Width | Length| Height,
    }
```

So I can have (that means that it fit on that side):

```
width = Width | Length | Height  /// 111
length = Width                   /// 001
height = Width                   /// 001
```

basically my method should be something like

```
bool FitIn (Size container)
{
    En_Dimension width = En_Dimension.None; 
    En_Dimension length = En_Dimension.None;
    En_Dimension height = En_Dimension.None;

    for(var do in this.Dimensions){
        for (var db in container.Dimensions){
            if (do <= db) {
               // already implemented code to
               // SET width OR length OR height
            }
        }
    }

    /// EXAMPLES
    /// 001     001
    /// 110     001
    /// 010     111
    /// FIT     DON'T FIT

    return (/*width, length, height BIT LOGIC*/) == En_Dimension.All
}
```

The expected output of the example is `false` while it should return `true` only when it "fit" on all the lines in at least one not already fitted side.
Let's say this are the "valid" combination of ones

```
1**    1**    *1*    *1*    **1    **1
*1*    **1    1**    **1    1**    *1*
**1    *1*    **1    1**    *1*    1**
```

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the thing we need to compute is "given these masks, can we make 111 by selecting one position from each mask"?

Comment: @harold Yup, that's the idea.

Comment: By the way what language is this actually? I thought it was C# but it doesn't fit exactly

Comment: c# -ish just to give the idea of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with 6 tests, corresponding to each of the permutations:

```
int fittingDims = (int)width | ((int)length << 4) | ((int)height << 8);
return (fittingDims & 0x124) == 0x124 ||
       (fittingDims & 0x142) == 0x142 ||
       (fittingDims & 0x214) == 0x214 ||
       (fittingDims & 0x241) == 0x241 ||
       (fittingDims & 0x412) == 0x412 ||
       (fittingDims & 0x421) == 0x421;
```

There are no octal literals in C# so I used 4 bits per "block" to make the constants nice in hexadecimal.